# "Übungen zu diesem Kurs"-choice of preposition

Tags: preposition

Here are two sentences taken from one of the online dictionaries:

> Die Übungen zu diesem Kurs sind kostenlos.

> Ich kaufe die Karten fürs Konzert.

I fail to deduce the framework based on which one picks zu/für in these two sentences. The notion of purpose seems to be confined within each of them. How do you draw the line then?

Comment: Hoffen wir, dass die Übungen zu dem Kurs nicht für die Katz sind und die Karten auch den Zutritt zum Backstage-Bereich beinhalten... (und nein, leider keine Ahnung wie ich das formell beschreiben soll)

Answer (score 2):

> Die Übungen **für** diesen Kurs sind kostenlos.

*The exercises **for** that course are free.*

> Die Übungen **zu** diesem Kurs sind kostenlos.

*The excercises **coming with** that course are free.*

So the difference with this example is that the latter sentence says more explicit that the exercises are part of the package.

---

> Ich kaufe die Karten **fürs** Konzert.

*I buy the tickets **for the** concert.*

If you use *zum* in this example, the meaning is less clear and may be read as:

> Ich kaufe die Karten **zum** Konzert.

*I buy the tickets *because of* the concert.*

*I buy the tickets *in addition to* the concert (tickets.)*

*I buy the tickets *at* the concert.*